# MongoDB data pipeline to Redshift using Apache-Spark

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, amazon-redshift

As my employer makes the big jump to MongoDB, Redshift and Spark. I am trying to be proactive and get hands on with each of these technologies. Could you please refer me to any resources that will be helpful in performing this task -
"Creating a data pipeline using Apache Spark to move data from MongoDB to RedShift"

So, far I have been able to download a dev version of MongoDB and create a test Redshift instance. How do I go about setting the rest of the process and get my feet wet.

I understand to create the data pipeline using Apache Spark, one has to either code in Scala or Python or Java. I have a solid understanding of SQL, so feel free to suggest which language out of Scala, Python or Java would be easy for me to learn.

My background is in data warehousing, traditional ETL (Informatica, Datastage etc.).

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

A really good approach may be to use AWS Data Migration Services
[http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.MongoDB.h](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.MongoDB.html)tml

you can specify mongodb as a source endpoint and redshift as the target endpoint